# Can a C# SQL Parameter Contain '='

Tags: c#, sql

So I am trying to create parameters to pass to my query and was wondering if I could pass a parameter that contains an '=' sign in it that replaces the traditional '=' sign in the SQL statement. It would be like the following:

```
string aoi = "=" + comboBox1.Text;
string comp = "=" + comboBox2.Text;
//Default values of their respective Combo Boxes.
if(aoi == "Area Of Interest")
      aoi = "!= NULL";
if (comp == "Company")
      comp = "!= NULL";
cmd.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM JobListInfo" +
                  "WHERE AreaOfInterest @AOI AND Company @Company";
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@AOI", aoi);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Company", comp);
```

The reason I am asking is because if the user doesn't change the default value, I want it to pull all the records (with respect to the rest of the SQL statement). I understand I could create an OR statement, but I have three other parameters I would like to pass as well and didn't want to create 15 OR cases.

**EDIT:** I found a solution to my problem. I changed the '=' to Like and changed the strings to '%' if they didn't select a value. This shouldn't cause any SQL injection issues, right?
Sample Code:

```
if(aoi == "Area of Interest")
       aoi = "%"
cmd.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM JobListInfo " +
                  "WHERE AreaOfInterest LIKE @AOI";

cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@AOI", aoi);
```

Comment: 1. you're open to sql injections 2. `(aoi == "Area Of Interest")` is always false 3. use `is null` or `is not null` to compare with nulls

Comment: The operator would just be part of the variable. You cannot pass an operator as part of a parameter and have it actually do anything. You *could* build a dynamic SQL statement. That would be acceptable as long as it does not actually use user input as part of the statement itself.

Comment: I would suggest building the query accordingly in code depending if it is a default or not. What you suggest essentially is exactly what you want to avoid by paremeterizing your query.

Comment: In short, no. This is one of the reasons for parameterisation - to avoid SQL Injection. If a user entered ";DROP TABLE JobListInfo" into the textbox, you could be in for some fun...Manadatory Reference (https://xkcd.com/327/)

Comment: @Lashane Thanks for pointing #2 out. It would have to be (aoi == "= Area of Interest"). So what I am getting then is that I should just create OR cases for each parameter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not via a parameter.  If this were allowed, it would potentially introduce SQL injection vulnerabilities.

A potential solution would be to dynamically create the CommandText string by appending database column names and parameter placeholders to the query's WHERE clause.

WARNING: Do not append input values to the WHERE clause of your query string!  This will leave you vulnerable to SQL injection.  Instead, append parameter placeholders and then populate them using the cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue() method.

That being said, something like the code below might work.  However, it would depend on you selecting a single default value for your combo-boxes.  Consequently, you would need to use UI labels instead of default values to describe the combo-boxes in your app.

```
string MY_DEFAULT_VALUE = 'Pick One:';
string queryString = "SELECT * FROM my_table";

//Populate Dictionary:
Dictionary<string,ComboBox > columnDictionary= new Dictionary<string, ComboBox>();

columnDictionary.Add("COL_A", comboBox1);
columnDictionary.Add("COL_B", comboBox2);
columnDictionary.Add("COL_C", comboBox3);

//etc...

List<KeyValuePair<string, ComboBox>> appendedColumns = new List<KeyValuePair<string, ComboBox>>();

foreach (KeyValuePair<string, ComboBox> entry in columnDictionary)
{
    if (!String.Equals(entry.Value.Text, MY_DEFAULT_VALUE, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
    {
        string currentColumnName = entry.Key;
        string currentColumnParameter = "@" + entry.Key;

        if (appendedColumns.Count>1)
        {
            queryString += " AND ";
        }
        else
        {
            queryString += " WHERE ";
        }
        queryString += currentColumnName + " = " + currentColumnParameter;

        appendedColumns.Add(entry);
    }
}

cmd.CommandText = queryString;

if (appendedColumns.Count > 0)
{        
    foreach (KeyValuePair<string, ComboBox> entry in appendedColumns)
    {
        string currentColumnParameter = "@" + entry.Key;
        string currentParameterValue = entry.Value.Text;
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue(currentColumnParameter, currentParameterValue);
    }
}
//Continue on your way...
```

Answer (score 0):

Short answer to your question is, you cannot use '=' as you have shown. So change your code like this;

```
    string aoi = comboBox1.Text;
    string comp = comboBox2.Text;
    string sql;
    if (aoi == "Area Of Interest" && comp == "Company")
    {
        sql = @"SELECT * FROM JobListInfo WHERE AreaOfInterest Is Not NULL AND Company Is Not NULL";
    }
    else if(....)
    {
        sql =............................
    }
    else
    {
        sql = @"SELECT * FROM JobListIn WHERE AreaOfInterest = @AOI AND Company = @Company";
    }
    cmd.CommandText = sql;
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@AOI", aoi);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Company", comp);
```